# GIT: How can I do a pull request when I've already commited to my master branch?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch, git-pull

My remote repo's master branch looks like this (each one is a commit):

A - B - C - D - E - F - G

I would like to get a code review that diffs C and G (C's changes from B should not be displayed). How do I do this?

Do I have to

```
- create tmpBranch at master (pointing to G)
- branch from C (newBranch)
- move my master branch to newBranch
- delete newBranch
- push these branch changes to repo
- submit pull request
```

or is there an easier approach? If no, what are the commands that will do the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Branches are just labels to the HEAD commit.  So, you essentially just need to change the labels.

It's not a good idea to change public history, unless your repo is your own.  So, I'm assuming nobody uses your `master` branch.

```
$ git checkout G
$ git checkout -b review-this         # Create the branch to be reviewed.
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard C                  # Reset the master to commit C
$ git push -f <remote-name> master    # Force push the master branch
$ git push <remote-name> review-this  # Push the new branch
# Submit the pull request
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me after I committed to master on a project that was cloned from an open-source project. I later wanted to submit a pull request to the project, so I changed my old master to `myproject-master` and did the hard reset and pulled the open-source's master branch. Then I was able to collaborate on the open-source's project again. Thanks!